# Responder objetivamente à perguntas de inexperientes ou apontar melhores caminhos?

Tags: debate, comportamento, respostas

Muitas perguntas, principalmente dos menos experientes, apresentam uma abordagem ou conceitos errados, ou seja, está claro que a pessoa não está no caminho certo. Porém, muitas dessas perguntas podem ser facilmente respondidas.

O que é melhor nesses casos, responder objetivamente à pergunta, mesmo de certa forma incentivando o novato a seguir em frente em um caminho complicado ou não responder e apenas dar dicas a respeito de melhores abordagens?

[]s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dá pra fazer um misto.

## Nem sempre há um melhor absoluto

Veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54588/227), por exemplo. O usuário pergunta como fazer uma variável global, que para muitos é uma prática ruim.

O problema é que existem várias soluções para isso e elas podem ser consideradas boas ou más práticas para diferentes pessoas em diferentes situações.

Nesses casos, é interessante ter várias respostas ou várias alternativas em uma resposta, explicando as vantagens e desvantagens de cada abordagem.

## Responda a pergunta *e* aponte um caminho

[Nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54688/227) o autor também pergunta algo que "não deveria" ou não pode ser feito.

As respostas então dão a melhor alternativa. Na minha resposta, tendo explicar porque ele não deveria fazer aquilo mesmo que fosse possível.

## Um misto de tudo

[Nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54570/227) o autor também pergunta por algo que é uma má prática, mas  entendo que em raras situações isso até seria aceitável. Portanto, respondi o autor dizendo que há alternativas melhores, mas se ele tiver razões para fazer daquele jeito, também respondi como fazer.